# 'http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: server

```
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'nginx/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Comment: Are you using 18.04 or 16.04? It seems you've mixed up repository information of one with the other.

Comment: ubuntu 16.04... 64bit system

Comment: Customer support give the solution, but i dont know how to solve .. please help me....You will need to review your apt sources.list file. You have a 32bit repo included, however you are running a 64 bit OS.

Comment: It's not an error. Errors start with "E:" It's merely a Notification ("N:") and does not need to be 'fixed', because nothing is broken.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a message I would worry about. I get the same thing on my Google Earth entry:

`deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main`

Now, I can edit this line to say this, which gets rid of the error:

```
deb [ arch=amd64 ] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
```

The problem is that every time Google Earth updates, it overwrites my changes. If you make the change to your nginx repo, it could do the same thing.

Comment: but i try same thing .. still i am getting error

Comment: Show me your nginx repo line, please.

Comment: deb [ arch=amd64 ] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main

Comment: That's the wrong entry. It looks like you added the nginx PPA; you need to find that file first. Also, as @Kulfy pointed out, your repo information is mixed up; on your system, your repos should be using **xenial**, not **bionic**.